# Как подключить два класса в одной функции jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, синтаксис, функции

С синтаксисом jQuery плохо знаком. Есть функция с кучей опций.

```
$('.class-a').function({
    option: 'a',
    option: 'b',
    option: 'c'
});
```

Можно ли как-нибудь подключить class-b к этой же функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте, на сколько я помню надо сделать так:

> $('.class-a, .class-b').function({
>     option: 'a',
>     option: 'b',
>     option: 'c'
> });

Если надо чтобы функция выполнялась на элементах которые принадлежат и классу а и классу б (пересечение) тогда

> $('.class-a.class-b').function({
>     option: 'a',
>     option: 'b',
>     option: 'c'
> });

Comment: Добрый день. Нет, классы не наследуемые друг от друга, расположены в разных местах. Я просто не хочу писать `$('.class-a').function({ опции }); , $('.class-b').function({ опции });` Думал можно как-то через запятую два класса прицепить к одной функции

Comment: P.S Функция одна и таже

Comment: Пффф, я тормоз извините =)
Так растерялся перед jquery что весь css синтаксис из головы вылетел,
$('.class-a, .class-b') То что нужно, спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста :-) А ведь и правда синтаксис напоминает наследование :-)